# Can I update Apache Atlas metadata by adding a message directly into the Kafka topic？

Tags: apache-kafka, atlas

I am trying to add a message to Entities_Topic to update the kafka_Topic type metadata in Apache Atlas. I wrote the data according to the JSON format of Message, but it didn't work.
application.log is displayed as follows:

```
graph rollback due to exception AtlasBaseException:Instance kafka_topicwith unique attribute {qualifiedName=atlas_test00@primary # clusterName to use in qualified name of entities. Default: primary} does not exist (GraphTransactionInterceptor:202)
graph rollback due to exception AtlasBaseException:Instance __AtlasUserProfile with unique attribute {name=admin} does not exist(GraphTransactionInterceptor:202)
```

And here is the message I passed into Kafka Topic earlier:

```
{"version":{"version":"1.0.0","versionParts":[1]},"msgCompressionKind":"NONE","msgSplitIdx":1,"msgSplitCount":1,"msgSourceIP":"192.168.1.110","msgCreatedBy":"","msgCreationTime":1664440029000,"spooled":false,"message":{"type":"ENTITY_NOTIFICATION_V2","entity":{"typeName":"kafka_topic","attributes":{"qualifiedName":"atlas_test_k1@primary # clusterName to use in qualifiedName of entities. Default: primary","name":"atlas_test01","description":"atlas_test_k1"},"displayText":"atlas_test_k1","isIncomplete":false},"operationType":"ENTITY_CREATE","eventTime":1664440028000}}
```

It is worth noting that there is no GUID in the message and I do not know how to create it manually. Also, I changed the time according to the timestamp of the current time. The JSON is passed in through the Kafka tool Offset Explorer.

My team leader wants to update the metadata by sending messages directly into Kafka, and I'm just trying to see if that's possible.
How can I implement this idea, or please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from writing to the topic, right? But if the event is invalid, then the Atlas consumer would completely fail, so I suggest you use proper avenues for getting data into that topic

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will give it a try, but I think there is something wrong with the identifier code.